# Access an injected service from within a Class decorator? Typescript / NestJS

Tags: typescript, decorator, nestjs

Is it possible to access an injected service from within a Class decorator?

I want to get the service within the custom constructor:

```
function CustDec(constructor: Function) {
  var original = constructor;

  var f: any = function (...args) {
    // I want to get injectedService here. How?
    // I've tried things like this.injectedService but that doesn't work
    return new original(...args);
  }

  f.prototype = target.prototype;
  return f;
}

@CustDec
@Injectable()
class MyService {
  constructor(
    private readonly injectedService: InjectedService,
  ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [official class-decorator docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators), here's a way that should work:

```
function CustDec<T extends new(...args: any[]) => {}>(Target: T) {
    return class extends Target {
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
            (args[0] as InjectedService).doSomething();
        }
    }
}

@CustDec
@Injectable()
class MyService {
  constructor(
    private readonly injectedService: InjectedService,
  ) {}
}
```

I've also created an example on [TS-Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAYRAZygEQKYQDwAqi2AHlNmACZqIDeiY2A7gBQB0HAhgE4DmaALkScwATwDaAXQCUQ2gF9E8gHwsCPXtihCC0ugChERxNy0huSCABtOaGqXJUa6vloPGPiCAgzcQ0OG52Lj5BYTEpPVpDT1i0EAAHbCCONg00aQBuGNiPFnTxAAZJYRoASTAAK1xySgBlZIA3GAhsaTZKODq4AFstAAsYMF4WLJzPeXHJyf1rW3Kqmux6ppbsaI9O7r6oQeHRjdzvMDQ4K2w2KzgRgCImGCsrRAAjbEQr3k1KRESELx8oH4AtxEENGnAIJxYAgbmMPNN9PoAAKoDA4CCzGx2RAAWVEDW4zVa7n%20J0B-iggRY4wS3BgjShb1MnE6YCsokQpz6BKJ2AEFWq0GWPLWABoYlEEbMAZzEABeBjMXH41atFiMJiIAVLFaEtajLJAA).

Comment: This worked except I got a TSLint error: `Type literal has only a call signature — use \`new (...args: any[]) => {}\` instead.`


To fix, I replaced the first line with this:


`function CustDec<T extends new(...args: any[]) => {}>(Target: T) {`

Comment: Happy to help - updated to your solution in case anyone else has the same issue.